# How can I solve this tangent drawing game problem?

Tags: geometry

I need to draw tangents through point A in a figure below.

I tried to solve the problem by using a fact that a tangent, a radius and a line connecting a center and A form a right triangle. But I can't make any further progress.

[image]

**Rules**

- Nodes have integer Euclidean (x, y) coordinates
- You can only pick nodes inside a canvas and connect them to draw a line
- You can pick a point with noninteger coordinates if you draw a line and make an intersection
- The game doesn't  complain about whether a canvas is dirty or not by temporary drawings

FYI, the name of the game is Pythagorea

Comment: May you draw circles?

Comment: @MichaelHoppe I'm afraid I can't. Only points and lines.

Comment: So you can't use a compass?

Comment: @Jens That's right

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you can figure out why is that.

[image]

---

Added:-

[image]

Let the length of one grid be 1 unit. Then, we have the following:-

1) radius = the diagonal of each grid $= \sqrt 2$; 2) $OP = \dfrac {\sqrt 2}{2}$.

Applying sine law to $\triangle OMT$, we get $\angle OTM =30^0$.

In $\triangle OTP$, we found $\dfrac {OP}{OT} = \dfrac {1}{2}$ after some calculation. This means $\angle TPO$ is right angled. We can then say $MPNT$ is a straight line.

Comment: Wow, it works. Let me think... Did you use congruence of triangles? I can clearly see one right triangle (including point A and origin). And also see another right triangle (including a diameter) and they are congruent. Not sure whether you used this property.

Comment: Uh... maybe not... Let me think again...

Comment: Thought again, and I think you used similarity of two right triangles sharing the tangent as one side. Is it correct?

Comment: @Jeon Yes. Similarity is one part towards the solution. I will add some details to my post.... minutes later.