# Explaining solutions to Pythagorea puzzle 2.16: Drawing a line through a given point parallel to a given line

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, puzzle, geometric-construction

> In this geometry puzzle (Problem 2.16 of the game "Pythagorea"), a 6x6 grid is given. Inside the grid there's a black line and a point A not on the line. The goal is to draw a line through A parallel to the given black line.
>
> [image]

The solution must be achieved by drawing lines between points, including the starting grid points, the intersections between the grid and the given black line, and new points/intersections that appear after drawing more lines. Circles cannot be drawn.
Everything must be done within the grid, the grid cannot be extended.

There's no limit to the number of steps/lines used before getting to the solution. And there are several ways to arrive at the solution, but the last step is always drawing the intended parallel line, e.g. the second-to-last step creates a point B so that joining A and B creates the intended parallel line.

If from this description and the first image you can figure out a way to the solution, feel free to explain it. Otherwise, see the second and third images. The parallel line shows in yellow and the other construction lines in blue.

This is a 3-step solution:

[image]

This is a 2-step solution:

[image]

This last image shows both solutions for comparison.

[image]

The question is:

> How do these solutions work? What theorems are applied in each one?

Thank you

Comment: This appears to be mostly spam/advertising. If you have a legitimate question under all of that, can you tone it down?

Comment: @MishaLavrov as in making the post shorter?

Comment: As in making the post about math, rather than about why everyone should play this mobile game.

Comment: The post is not about why EVERYONE should play this game. The post is about a MATH puzzle featured in this game. The 
ruless have to be given. I have seen similar quesrions such as the one below. Do you think I should remove all references to the game such as the name? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1960368/how-can-i-solve-this-tangent-drawing-game-problem

Comment: I am astonished by the previously posted comments.  At the time of this comment, there is no indication that the original posting has been edited.  The original posting is presenting two very clear cut geometric math problems: for each of the two solutions, provide geometric analysis to support the allegation that the corresponding construction is viable under the "straight edge + compass" constraint, or under whatever constraints apply to the particular game.

Comment: Re my last comment, personally, I am generally uneducated in geometry, so I can't answer the question(s).  However, I can still comprehend the questions well enough to recognize that the questions are not meaningless.

Comment: Perhaps the issue is with the first paragraphs, where I give a brief intro to the rules before getting into the problem. I can remove it or put it last so that people see the problem first and foremost. That's what the other user did in the other linked question. But I need @MishaLavrov to confirm if that would be OK

Comment: @bob93 That would be a good thing to do. You don't need me to confirm if that would be okay; it's a straightforward improvement to the problem. Begin by asking the mathematical question; the fact that it comes from a game you can download on your phone is mostly-irrelevant context.

Comment: First solution: It's a consequence of Thales Theorem.  $\quad$ Second solution: Recognize that the slope of the line of 3/5. If you had a larger grid, this would be easy. Unfortunately you can't move 5 units horizontally from A.  $\quad$ Somewhat importantly, these solutions do not easily generalize to arbitrary starting positions (esp those that don't involve lattice grid points)

Comment: @CalvinLin Consequence of Thales'? Really? What I don't understand is how they figured that triangle would be a right triangle. I can see how you can get the slope once you have a perpendicular. But how they got that peroendicular/right triangle baffles me

Comment: @bob93 Did you check carefully whether the mentioned triangle of the first solution is a right triangle?

Comment: @bob93 Ah, sorry for the ambiguity. I was referring to the [Intercept theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intercept_theorem) which is also known as Thale's theorem. It's basically about similar triangles. (Not about right angles in circles)

Comment: @YNK wow, it looks like that may not be a right triangle, which makes things even more mysterious!

Comment: @bob93 The 2×3 & 3×5 triangles look similar because the sides are succesive Fibonacci numbers, which makes the angle close to 90°. But clearly 2/3 doesn't equal 3/5, so they aren't actually similar triangles. More Fibonacci triangle fun: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gist/PM2Ring/fbe0ea1cb434602ca3a90060e4c55493/raw/64-65_paradox.svg

Answer (score 5):

You can show that the two solutions are correct by using similar triangles. In the diagram of the first solution below, $\ AB,CD,FG\ $ and $\ HI\ $ are all parallel. Therefore, by similarity of triangles $\ EAB\ $ and $\ ECD\ $ we have $\ EA:EC=$$\,AB:CD=$$\,1:3\ $ and by similarity of triangles $\ EFG\ $ and $\ EHI\ $ we have $\ EG:EI$$\,=EF:EH$$\,=1:3\ .$ Therefore $\ EA:EC=$$\,EG:EI$$\,=1:3\ ,$ triangles $\ EAG\ $ and $\ ECI\ $ must be similar, and $\ AG\ $ must be parallel to $\ CI\ $.

[image: Diagram 1]

In the diagram of the second solution below $\ GI:HI=$$\,3:5\ $, so the slope of the line $\ HG\ $ is $\ \frac{3}{5}\ .$ Do you see how the similar triangles $\ DEF\ $ and $\ DBC\ $ can be used to show that the slope of the line $\ AF\ $ is the same?

[image]

Here's a third solution which seems to me to be simpler than either of the above.  In the diagram below, the lengths of the lines $\ BC\ $ and $\ AC\ $ are clearly $\ \frac{3}{2}\ $ units and $\ \frac{5}{2}\ $ units, respectively, making the slope of the line $\ AB\ $ $\ \frac{3}{5}\ ,$ the same as that of the given line.

[image]

**Additional solutions**

As Calvin Lin points out in [his answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4819451/explaining-solutions-to-pythagorea-puzzle-2-16-drawing-a-line-through-a-given-p/4820062#4820062) there are many more solutions besides those listed above.  Besides the grid lines through $\ A\ ,$ the target line intersects $5$ other vertical grid lines and $3$ other horizontal grid lines.  Each of those $8$ intersections can be obtained in one step, just as in the second of the solutions given in OP's question. All $8$ of the resulting solutions are shown in the diagram below.

[image]

Comment: Nice third solution. Ultimately it boils down to which point on that line we want to construct, and how.

Comment: lonza, very clear explanation, and now we have 4 solutions in total. Amazing!

Comment: Oh, there are many more solutions than those $4.$ As Calvin Lin has pointed out in his answer, you can obtain other solutions by constructing lines which have common intersections with those where the target line intersects any grid line. I've now added another diagram to my answer which illustrates 8 two-step solutions obtained in this way (one of which is just the second one you give in your question).

Comment: There are in fact an infinite number of solutions.  Any point whose coordinates are [dyadic rationals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadic_rational) between $0$ and $6$ can be obtained as the intersection of $2$ lines that are constructible within the rules, and there are an infinite number of such points lying on the target line.

Comment: I believe a point can be obtained as the intersection of 2 lines that are constructible within the rules if and only if its coordinates are rational numbers between 0 and 6. I'm reasonably sure a proof of this is fairly easy, but since I haven't written it out in detail, I'm not prepared to assert this as an incontrovertible fact.

Comment: I think there are at least ten more two-step solutions; see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4821061/139123 (which would just have been a comment here except I don't think I can include a picture in a comment).

Comment: A necessary condition for a node is that the coordinates are rational and that the denominator has prime factors 2, 3, or 5  only. I believe that all of these points are also constructible on the $ 6 \times 6$ grid (but only have a hand-wavy proof, mainly due to the edge restrictions of going off the page).

Comment: @lonzaleggiera the last image you added was created using Pythagorea. Did you download it just to make that image, or are you an active player of the game as well?

Comment: @CalvinLin I wonder about the prime factors of the denominator. Using the prime factors $2$ and $5$ we can construct points dividing the edge of each small square in $10$ equal parts. Connect these points horizontally and vertically, and we have a $60\times60$ grid. Repeat and we have a $600\times600$ grid. It seems we should be able to construct a line whose slope is $1/n$ for any integer $n$ by repeating this step until the grid has more than $n\times n$ squares, and then we can construct lengths whose denominators have a factor of $1/n$.

Comment: @DavidK Oh yes, good point! So it should be all rational points, even on the edges.

Comment: @Calvin Lin Yes.  By repeatedly drawing the diagonals across smaller and smaller squares you can obviously find two lines constructible within the rules whose point of intersection has arbitrary dyadic rational coordinates.

Comment: Now if $\ p\ $ and $\ q\ $ are any two positive integers, with $\ q\le 6p\ ,$ and $\ 2^n\ge\max\left(\frac{p}{5},\frac{q}{6}\right)\ $, then the line through the points with coordinates $\ (0,0)\ $ and $\ \left(\frac{p}{2^n},\frac{q}{2^n}\right)\ $ and the one through the points with coordinates $\ (1,0)\ $ and $\ \left(\frac{p}{2^n}+1,\frac{q}{2^n}\right)\ $ are both constructible within the rules.

Comment: The first of these intersects the line $\ x=1\ $ at the point with coordinates $\ \left(1,\frac{q}{p}\right)\ ,$ while the second intersects the line $\ x=2\ $ at the point with coordinates $\ \left(2,\frac{q}{p}\right)\ .$ Thus, the line through these last two points—namely, $\ y=\frac{q}{p}\ $—is constructible within the rules. Likewise, the line $\ x=\frac{q}{p}\ $ is also constructible within the rules.

Comment: @bob93 The only role Pythagorea played in creating the images I uploaded stems from your use of it to create the originals.  I simply downloaded the images you posted in your question and added the extra elements to them with Apple's Pages word processor.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the solution you have asked for.  We just want to show you that the angle of the triangle appeared in the first solution is not equal to $90^o$. At the same time, we include another solution for your perusal. It was obtained by drawing a line joining $H$ and $G$ to intersect a vertical grid line at $O$.

[image: Puzzle]

Comment: Yes, yes. I had assumed it was a right triangle because it looked liked one, but turning my head I can see it clearly is not. And that's an interesting solution. Is G exactly at that subdivision of the square? In the game you don't have those subdivisions but it may still be possible to get that point. Thank you

Comment: $G$ is the point of intersection between the given line and the right-border of the 6x6 grid. The $2^\text{nd}$ paragraph of your problem statement says that the solution must be achieved by drawing lines between points including the $ \bf{\text{intersections between the grid and the given black line}}$. Therefore, we thought $G$ was accessible. Don’t you think so?

Comment: Absolutely, that's correct. Still, by your graphic, it looks like G is located 2/5 of a unit below one of the grid lines. That's what got my attention. I'll look into veryfing wether this is actually the case or only an appearance

Comment: The diagram was drawn to scale.  The $x-$ and $y-$coordinates of $G$ are $\large{\bf{\left(6,\space 3.6\right)}}$.

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, here are a few more two-step solutions to add to the grid from
[this earlier answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4820040/139123).
The added solutions are shown as thin black lines.

[image]

One of the solutions comes from
[yet another answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4819945/139123),
one is the same (extended) line as one of the solutions already shown, but there are three ways to choose the two points to draw that line
(or at least two, anyway; the rules were not entirely clear).
One of the solutions is derived from the "three-step solution" by omitting the construction line through A. (The other construction line connects two grid points and can be constructed immediately without needing the line through A.)

Comment: You're right, in the 3 step solution in OP the first line is not necessary

Answer (score 0):

- Note that unlike pure compass-and-straightedge construction questions, you actually have a lot more guidance in playing around.
- You have grids, which means that the initial nodes are lattice points. And since you're connecting nodes with lines, those slopes are rational. In fact, the nodes that you can define would all have rational coordinates (I believe, but haven't fully double checked.)
- Because you have grid lines, cutting lines up into $ \frac{1}{3}, \frac{2}{3}, \frac{1}{5}, \frac{2}{5}, \ldots $ can be done easily under certain conditions.

**Solution 1 explained - Similar triangles**

- Starting off with point $A$ and line $BC$.
- Notice that $AB$ is easily a "multiple of 4", and hence a "multiple of 2". We can easily bisect $AB$ (at point X, unlabelled) and might be able to work with that point.
- If we extend $AB$ out by 1/2 to $D$, and observe that $DC$ is both a "multiple of 2 and 3" which gives us lots of options, we can trisect $DC$ with point E, Y (unlabelled).
- Then, $AE \parallel XY \parallel BC$.

**Solution 2 explained - Coordinate geometry**

- Observe that $BC$ has a slope of $\frac{3}{5}$.
- $B = (0, 0), C = (5, 3), A = (2, 4)$.
- To find the line parallel through $A$ (which we'd call $\ell$), we just need another point on it.
- If we chose the vertical grid line that $C$ is on ($y=5$), then that will intersect $\ell$ at $H = (5, 4 + 3\times \frac{3}{5}) = (5, 5 \frac{4}{5} )$.
- So we want to snip off $ \frac{1}{5} $ from the top, which can be done by constructing at line of slope $ \frac{ 1}{5}$.
- Hence construct $FG$ intersecting $ y = 5$ at $H$.
- Note: We could take lots of other lines. Solution 1 could be interpreted as choosing the line $x=5$, and then figuring out where and how to cut it up. As such, on your end, you should choose another line (say $x = 3$), and figure out how to construct the point which gives the intersection with $\ell$.

[image]

Comment: I like how you look at the first solution, and the proposal after the explanation of the second solution, even though I don't know coordinate geometry